# How to display notebook model number?

Tags: command-line, hardware, system-info

I have a notebook HP Pavilion dm4 running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to determine the model number (like HP Pavilion dm4-2015dx or HP Pavilion dm4-2033cl, etc).
There's no such information on notebook's body as suggested [on HP's website](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&cc=us&docname=c00033108&dlc=en&product=1842189) on **Option 1**.

I tried to use `lshw` and `dmidecode`, but couldn't find. Maybe I should use an especific option but all the information I found is for Windows, nothing for linux.

There is a way to show this information on linux?

---

`sudo dmidecode |grep Version`

shows

`Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M 460 @ 2.53GHz`

---

Here's the `System Information` part of `sudo dmidecode | less`

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
        Product Name: HP Pavilion dm4 Notebook PC     
        Version: 058A120000242B10000020100
        Serial Number: 5CA1062FYJ
        UUID: E4BD398B-4D9E-BC63-1A03-099330BF5443
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: XZ299UAR#ABA
        Family: 103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=PAV        
:
```

Comment: are you sure about dmidecode not showing the extra model numbers?

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried to compare the result of `dmidecode` and the list of models on HP website and couldn't find a match.

Comment: I used your SKU Number and found your Netbook.

`HP Pavilion dm4-1253cl XZ299UAR`

Comment: Asus laptop + ubuntu 17.04 works. Thanks!

Comment: @efthialex
How to find model number using sku number?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal It has been a long time, but as far as I remember, I have found it on the HP website

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal just by googling it, it will bring your laptop's exact model.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

To see your model number, open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`sudo dmidecode | grep Version | sed -n '2p'`

or alternatively type:

`sudo dmidecode | grep 'SKU Number' | head -1`

to see your SKU Number.

---

If you want to see a more detailed view of your System information type:

`sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information"`

or

`sudo dmidecode | less`

and use the  <kbd>**↓**</kbd>  key to go to the section *System Information*.

[image]

Comment: Tried to do that, but the information is just:

`Product Name: HP Pavilion dm4 Notebook PC`

Comment: `Pavilion dm4` is the model of you laptop.

Comment: I know, but there is a "sub model" (called model number), so it should be `Pavilion dm4-xxxx` or something similar.

Comment: @EduardoGoncalves The number you are looking for is the `Version` number. For example my Laptop is:

`TOSHIBA Satellite c660 PSC0QE`

Comment: The version number is `Version: 058A120000242B10000020100`. I tried to find a model similar to that number, like `dm4-058A12`, `dm4-58A12`,`dm4-5812` and so on, but there's no such thing.

Comment: @EduardoGoncalves Please post the results of `sudo dmidecode | less` in your question. Only the _System Information_ section.

Comment: You have a [useless use of less](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) in your first 2 examples `sudo dmidecode | grep Version` is enough

Comment: @lolesque fixed.

Comment: this showed me `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name`

Answer (score 27):

I guess this command will help:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep 'SKU Number' | head -1
```

This will return your laptop's model name:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
```

This will return your serial number:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number
```

`-s` is a keyword argument. Run `man dmidecode` to find all the available options.

Comment: This is the best answer. I am on a Mac Mini and neither 'SKU Number' nor 'Version' turn up the serial number (searching for 'Serial' does, but there are several). `sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number` did the trick.

Answer (score 17):

**Use dmidecode**

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 1

#dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
       Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
       Product Name: Latitude E6410
       Version: 0001
       Serial Number: DZX46BS
       UUID: 4C4C4544-005A-5810-8034-C4C04F364253
       Wake-up Type: Power Switch
       SKU Number:  
       Family: Not Specified
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.  Although the `t` option might be interesting, you should refrain from using `root` as an account and type `sudo` instead.  Refer to the many documents existing on the topic for further info.

Comment: Good answer , works.

Answer (score 3):

On my T430 I have to take out the battery and there is this little sticker that tells me exactly what I want to know. It's not where Lenovo says it is (on top of the battery), but there it is. Might be easier than doing it from the command line if in fact you have such a sticker.

Comment: I tried that to but couldn't find this sticker anywhere. It was the first thing I thought, but it's missing

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to get my model number within neofetch information, specifically under 'Host' info.

```
neofetch
```

You may need to install neofetch to run this. It can be done by

```
sudo apt install neofetch
```